# Serving files with static webserver on debian (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amazon-web-services, debian, webserver

I'm working on migrating my localhost website to
a live one, hosted on amazon web services lightsail (Linux+App [Debian] -> wordpress).
I've configured wordpress correctly, but I'm here because my web browser is sending me the error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when i'm trying to visiting the page My_page on wordpress. This page imports my backend javascript files.
Some additional info:
"My_page" works with an Elementor frontend and then I have a plugin (Custom css and js) where I have written this code:

```
<script src="http://example.com:8887/cnr_abi.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com:8887/DAPP_BUILDATA.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com:8887/styleCSS.css">
```

which is appended after the  tag.

Asking why i put the port after the src attribute? because when i'm working on localhost[windows] I have a static web server that serves my files on port 8887, with a software called FenixWebServer and all works correctly. So in thius debian machine I've tried using BusyBox by running this command to serve my files (stored in the folder /home/bitnami/BackendFolder) -> busybox httpd -p 8887 -h path_correct but is not working when I try to connect from my chrome browser on my pc to the server. Can anybody help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there more to that error? This might be caused by content security policy.

Comment: No there is not, but im thinking about this too, how can i grant content security?

Comment: It's going to be in the headers that your server sends with the html. I don't know your server.

Comment: Which header should i put in my headers that i send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set Alias on the apache virtual host configuration file.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
<Directory "/var/www/miodominio.com/public">
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```